# Capturar texto dentro de uma <td> via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, knockoutjs, text

Como faço para pegar somete o valor (R$11,20)?

```
<td class="monetary" databind = "text: value label, visible: $parent.isShippingKnown()">R$11,20 </td>
```

Não deu certo, e tem essa outra estrutura, preciso somente do texto: 
"R$ 8,62 - Até 8 dias úteis"

```
<span data-bind="text: maxEstimateOptionText">Econômica - R$ 8,62 - Até 8 dias úteis</span>


$('#Econômica').text(); // Retorna
$('#Convencional).text(); // Retorna
$('#Rápida).text(); //Retorna
$('#Entrega Agendada I Convencional').text(); // Não Retorna
$('#Entrega Agendada I Sábado').text(); // Não retorna


<li data-bind="attr: {'class': idAttr}, css: { selected: name == $parent.selectedSlaName() }" class="seller-BTP-sla-EntregaAgendadaISabado">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.selectedSlaName(name) }, attr: { 'id': name }" id="Entrega Agendada I Sábado">
        <i class="icon-ok" data-bind="visible: name == $parent.selectedSlaName()" style="display: none;"></i> &nbsp;
        <span data-bind="text: maxEstimateOptionText">Entrega Agendada I Sábado - A partir de R$ 76,20 - Primeira data em 06/08/2016</span>
    </a>
</li>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.selectedSlaName(name) }, attr: { 'id': name }" id="Entrega Agendada I Sábado">
    <i class="icon-ok" data-bind="visible: name == $parent.selectedSlaName()" style="display: none;"></i> &nbsp;
    <span data-bind="text: maxEstimateOptionText">Entrega Agendada I Sábado - A partir de R$ 76,20 - Primeira data em 06/08/2016</span>
</a>
<i class="icon-ok" data-bind="visible: name == $parent.selectedSlaName()" style="display: none;"></i> &nbsp;
<span data-bind="text: maxEstimateOptionText">Entrega Agendada I Sábado - A partir de R$ 76,20 - Primeira data em 06/08/2016</span>
```

Comment: Tens acesso ao código do servidor que gera esse HTML? assim podias passar isso num atributo `data-` e era bem mais seguro e fácil.

Comment: Somente uma curiosidade:
Se quiser capturar o texto de dentro de um select apenas do que foi selecionado o código seria o seguinte: var texto = $('#id_do_select :selected').text();

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei como é o resto da estrutura do HTML, mas um código assim resolve para o caso apresentado:

```
$("td.monetary").text();
```

Pela estrutura parece que você está usando knockoutjs, se estiver existem outras opções.

Comment: Estou usando a biblioteca knockout-2.3.0.js sim Douglas. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: estou usando a biblioteca knockout-2.3.0.js sim Douglas. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Eu não sei qual a estrutura do seu Model para o Knockoutjs, mas você pode acessar diretamente o valor pelo seu modelo.(seuobjeto).maxEstimateOptionText(). Isso para o segundo caso.

Comment: Você poderia colocar mais informações?  O primeiro caso está dentro de um data-bind="foreach: " ?

Comment: @BrunoNascimento, eu preciso de um exemplo melhor do seu HTML, eu vi a sua edição, mas eu não sei quais são os Ids que você está utilizando em seus elementos.

Comment: Eu melhorei a descrição @Douglas Fernandes, só estava estruturando, acho que agora está completa. Como disse, não consegui selecionar as entregas agendadas. Me desculpe a bagunça, se precisar que edite, pode falar. Grato desde já!

Comment: @BrunoNascimento, você pode tentar fazer algo deste tipo                  $(".seller-BTP-sla-EntregaAgendadaISabado span").text();                  . Mas eu acho que não é o caso. Pela sua lógica também pode tentar algo assim $(".seller-BTP-sla-EntregaAgendadaISabado.selected span").text();

Comment: Ou você pode tentar fazer algo deste tipo no Knockout: var TextEsperado;
    foreach( var i in objeto.<ListagemDoseuModelo>()){
     
     if(objeto.<ListagemDoseuModelo>()[i].name == $parent.selectedSlaName()){
     TextEsperado = objeto.<ListagemDoseuModelo>()[i].maxEstimateOptionText(); break;
     }
    
    }

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemple de como tirar o texto de um elemento do HTML e manipula-lo. Nesse exemplo eu peguei o texto do DIV e o coloquei dentro de um Input.

Espero ter ajudado.

```js
$(function(){
    var valorDaDiv = $(".divdemonstracao").text();    
    $("#inputdemonstracao").val(valorDaDiv);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divdemonstracao">Produto teste 1</div>

<br><br>

Texto vai aparecer dentro do Input:<br>
<input type="text" id="inputdemonstracao">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Preciso somente do texto: "R$ 8,62 - Até 8 dias úteis"

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var span = $("span").text();    
  var dados = span.split("Econômica - ");
  console.log(dados[1]);
  alert(dados[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="text: maxEstimateOptionText">Econômica - R$ 8,62 - Até 8 dias úteis</span>
```